# Story about a person creating an universe for private client

Tags: story-identification

I would be grateful, if you help me identify this story.

It's a short novel in epistolary form.

It starts with letter where we learn that one specialist (recipient) was commissioned by private client (sender) to create an artificial universe.

As project was due, it was complete but lacked polish.
The client complained about anomalies, particularly ones involving a certain subject (an unnamed person) within universe .

Follow up is the answer from specialist, informing about changes to resolve problems. 
Is then followed by another letter from client about anomalies still existing.

Correspondence continues for longer period of time than parties anticipated ,as anomalies were found hard to fix. As result,parties (particularly specialist) seem to less happy about prolonged project.

In Final letter  specialist informs client , that he ultimately resolved all hardship, by simply removing that subject out of existence and there are no more observed anomalies including all the client mentioned ones, thus making project delivered.

I've read that story about 15 years ago. Book was old, printed before 1990 If remembered correctly . It was anthology, so novel will be older than that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you happen to remember any details of the cover?  You should check out the other [suggestions for story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any additional details to [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be [Robert Sheckley's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Sheckley) "[The Impacted Man](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56003)".

What you describe is a framing of the story about a man stuck in a "time fault" that makes him travel in time whenever he tries to go downstairs from his apartment.

You can find the story [here](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v50n04_1952-12_Gorgon776/page/n69/mode/2up).

Comment: I looked up and reading right now. It looks like is what I was searching for. perhaps I have missed some parts, being focused more on correspondence than man stuck.

Comment: I did recall a story about man meeting prehistoric savages. I might have misremembered that being other story not part  of this. So it's a match. Thank you. I'll mark as answer.

Comment: And by the way thanks for the link. Even with name known, old stories ain't always easy to find.
And thank you all for help.